# Cucumber: pipe output without losing color

Tags: colors, grep, cucumber, pipe, zsh

I'm using `cucumber` to run some tests.  It colorizes its output using ANSI escapes.  This is great, but currently its producing more output than I care about, and shoving things I do care about off the screen.  There doesn't seem to be a way to eliminate the other lines from within cucumber, but I can pipe the output through `grep` to pare down to the ones I care about.

The downside of this solution, though, is that all the colors are lost.  I know it's not my shell or grep's fault, because `% echo "\e[35mhello\e[00m world" | grep hello` works just fine, so it must be cucumber disabling its own color somehow.

How can I preserve the colored output when I pipe the output of cucumber?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Doh.  It's covered in `cucumber -h`.  Use the `-c` flag to force colorized output.

Comment: A lot of programs which produced colorized output often only do so when stdout is a terminal -- if stdout is a pipe, they will not use color.

Comment: True. `ls --color=auto` and `grep --color=auto` are two examples.